# Can i modify the Html.DisplayFor to show a substring of any charecter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5.2.2. web application using Razor view engine. I am trying to modify the default `Html.DisplayFor` to show substring of 100 character followed by "..." on certain views ? so is this possible to achieved ?
Thanks

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "default".  If you mean, can you modify the behavior of the built-in template, then no.  You can, however, replace the template with a template that does this.. but you would have to do any built-in datatype handling yourself.  There are a number of other approaches you could use, such as pre-truncating the value in your view model, using a jquery extension like jquery.dotdotdot, etc..

Answer (score 2):

`Html.DisplayFor` is a templated helper. MVC has some default templates built-in for the most common C# types. For a string, it's pretty much just dumps the string value as-is, though.

You can override the built-ins by adding your own display templates to `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\`. The views you add need to be named after one of three things:

1. A type (either standard C# types or you own classes), e.g. `String.cshtml`, `DateTime.cshtml`, `Boolean.cshtml`, etc.
2. A member of the `DataType` enum, e.g. `EmailAddress.cshtml`, `ImageUrl.cshtml`, etc. (this requires that the property be decorated with the appropriate `DataType` attribute)
3. Virtual anything you want in conjunction with decorating the property with the `UIHint` attribute. For example `[UIHint("Foo")]` would use a display template named `Foo.cshtml`.

In your case, you *could* use `String.cshtml` with contents of something like:

```
@model String

@Model.Substring(0, 100)&hellip;
```

However, I don't think you *really* want this to apply to every string rendered on your site, everywhere. Using `UIHint` with a custom display template is probably a better choices here. Create a display template named something like `TruncatedString.cshtml` and then decorate any properties you want displayed truncated like this with `[UIHint("TruncatedString")]`.

That's only if you insist on using `Html.DisplayFor`. Really, it would probably be better to add a string extension like:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this string s, int length, string suffix = "...", bool html = false)
    {
        s = s ?? string.Empty;
        s = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
        if (s.Length > length)
        {
            s = s.Substring(0, length + 1);
            s = s.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, s.LastIndexOf(" ") == -1 ? 0 : s.LastIndexOf(" ")));
            s = s + suffix;
        }

        if (html)
        {
            return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(s.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            return s.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, you can just do the following in your view:

```
@Model.SomeLongString.Truncate(100)
```

Comment: but if I use a string extension then any data annotation applied to the model property such as DateType.Date will not have any effect, while using DisplayFor will display the data based on any data annotation applied is this correct?

Comment: Well, yes, in the sense that the data type informs what template DisplayFor uses. However, if you're dealing with a string that you would use this extension with, there's no data type template you would need to use DisplayFor for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Editor Templates and UIHint's:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Personally my preference would be to create another read-only property in the model and have that return a truncated value. Probably using the truncate extension mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

you can user the next sentence:

@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.name_field).ToString().Substring(1, n)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateDate).ToString().Substring(0,10)
```